# Can't center Bootstrap card

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

I am trying to center a [card](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/card/)  in the middle of the screen, I could center it horizontally using `mx-auto` but couldn't center it vertically, I am trying to use `mt-3` to add a margin-top to the card but it give me like 1 centimeter margin-top, so what am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 mx-auto mt-2">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
                bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<meta>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/semantics.html#the-meta-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification. The same is true for all HTML tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the bootstrap card in centre of screen add extra class as shown below and remove the class mt-2.

```
<div class="row align-items-center vh-100">
```

Here, vh = viewport height
and 100 represents 100% of the viewport height.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Bootstrap [center elements position utility](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/position/#center-elements), namely `position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle`

```
<div class="col-3 position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
```

demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title><%= title %></title>
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-T3c6CoIi6uLrA9TneNEoa7RxnatzjcDSCmG1MXxSR1GAsXEV/Dwwykc2MPK8M2HN"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-3 position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
              <p class="card-text">
                Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the
                bulk of the card's content.
              </p>
              <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-C6RzsynM9kWDrMNeT87bh95OGNyZPhcTNXj1NW7RuBCsyN/o0jlpcV8Qyq46cDfL"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```